# Email Validation in jquery for already existing email with no return value

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-validate

I have used the following code for check existing email using jquery validation.
But it returns 1 if email address does not exists otherwise it returns 'please fix this field'.

I need the error message 'already exist' if it finds existing email. Otherwise it should not return any value.

```
            email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                    url: "<?php echo base_url().'payments/check_user_email'; ?>",
                    type: "post"
                 }
        }, 
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please Enter Email!",
                email: "This is not a valid email!",
                remote: "Email already in use!"
            }
        },
```

I also written the 'check_user_email' function in the php file like this,

```
function check_user_email()
{
 $email    = $this->input->post('email');
    if ($this->dx_auth->is_email_available($email))
    {
        echo TRUE;          
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo FALSE;
    }//If end 
}
```

Comment: Is your js in your php page, or included via `<script>`?

Comment: I have used <script> like above code

Comment: Any one help me.. why it returns 1 if it does not get any error?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 echo "TRUE"; OR echo "FALSE";
```

Make output as string. read more at [Here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/captcha/)